# Beginner programmer stuck on HW assignment - using Javascript to pull information from API

Tags: javascript, api, getelementbyid, var

I am in a beginner programming class and am struggling with our latest assignment. We've been asked to pull data from the Forecast IO weather API and return it to a HTML static page. I've gone into the Developer Tools > Console Log to find the variables that (I think) I need to query, define, and display.

Based on the screenshot below, I think I need to write the following script, but its returning as an undefined variable. Can anyone help me and let me know where I'm going wrong?

The code I've tried so far:

```
var Latitude = document.getElementById("hourly.latitude")
```

[image]

Comment: You do not use getElementById with an object. That would be your first issue.

Comment: Hey there, you should show your JavaScript code, and look up AJAX and JSON for guidance. W3Schools or Mozilla MDN

Comment: `document.getElementById()` is used to get a reference to a DOM Node, not a property in a Javascript object. You access object properties like any other programming language, simply `hourly.latitude`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use:

```
var Latitude = hourly.latitude
```

as hourly is a Javascript object and not an html element of the page.

See more information here [Javascript object reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)